# git checkout <commit> --

Tags: git, checkout, rebase

What I'm trying to do is to set repository to specific commit. For the situations like when I pull changes from origin/master, create my local branch and it's based on broken code so I want to rebase my branch to the 100% working commit which sha-1 is known.

I've tried

`git rebase <commit id>`

but head is detaching and it scares me.
Another idea was

`git checkout <commit id> -- .`

But I'm completely drown in git resets, cleans etc because of new (old) files and folders

So is there any other way to do this or `git rebase` is what I'm looking for?

Comment: When it completes successfully, [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) doesn't detach the `HEAD`. You end up with a detached `HEAD` probably because one commit cannot be applied clean and it produces merge conflicts. You need to resolve the conflicts (modify the conflicting files to look as you like), add them to the index and then run `git rebase --continue` to resume the rebasing.

Comment: Rebase means *copy some commits, then stop using the originals in favor of the new and improved copies*. If you do not intend to copy commits like this, do not use `git rebase`. If you just want to *use* some specific commit, a detached HEAD is ideal: just `git checkout origin/master`, for instance, to get a detached HEAD using the commit identified by your `origin/master`, which is your Git's way of remembering `origin`'s `master`.

Comment: If you have your own commits, and wish to repeatedly copy (and supposedly improve) them to new positions atop new commits you obtained from elsewhere, *do* use `git rebase`. If you have your own commits and wish to *combine* your work, *without* copying (and supposedly improving) your own commits, use `git merge`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just whack your current branch to point at a certain hash, `git reset` is what you're looking for. You can add `--soft` or `--hard` depending on if you want to keep any other changes around for recommitting or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exactly have the commit, just do

```
git reset --soft <commit>
```

in order to remove all commits after that commit and

```
git reset --hard
```

in order to ckeckout the latest commit(that you want) to the file system.

[**Note**]

This method deletes all local commits on that branch.

Comment: `git reset --hard <commit>` did the trick, else the changes afterwards are staged for a new commit